# First uses of integrals ever in history?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, math-history

**What are the 3 first uses ever of integrals in history, and for which specific reasons were they used for?** (formalized, so I'm not speaking about Archimedes attempts to calculate areas, 3rd century BC)

I guess it would be something like:

- Newton (date?) (maybe for a mechanics/physics problem, which one exactly?)
- Leibniz (date?) (for which problem?)
- ...

Comment: All right, so you are *not* “speaking about Archimedes attempts to calculate areas” (by the way, it wasn't merely an attempt; he *did* compute them). So, what *are* you speaking about? Do the areas computed by islamic mathematicians around 1000 AD count? After all, they used Archimedes as a role model. What about areas computed by Fermat? Or Isaac Barrow?

Comment: Bonaventura Cavalieri, Gilles Personne de Roberval...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean in a formalized way, with the integral sign, etc.

Comment: Integral sign: Leibniz.

Comment: @Basj So, you are *not* interested in the first integrations. What you are interested in are the first uses of the integral sign.

Comment: @Basj so you mean who introduced the symbol? modern formalization of these early ideas began as late as the nineteenth century, when people started to think more axiomatically about the reals.

Comment: For dates, see the pos [based-on-what-criteria-one-could-say-leibniz-invented-the-differential-calculus](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5011/based-on-what-criteria-one-could-say-leibniz-invented-the-differential-calculu).

Comment: For some useful references to dates and precursoes, see the post [when-was-the-inverse-relationship-between-tangents-and-quadrature-area-first-identified](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/when-was-the-inverse-relationship-between-tangents-and-quadrature-area-first-ide)

Comment: See also [why-are-integrals-called-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808285/why-are-integrals-called-integrals)

Comment: And see [why-was-the-term-integral-used-to-represent-the-area-under-a-curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238048/why-was-the-term-integral-used-to-represent-the-area-under-a-curve).